# Unity2d: Trying to change the color of a GameObject from a different class

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I can see that the GameObject is in the List but it gives me a "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" error when trying to change color to it.

```
public class Paint : MonoBehaviour
{
//inside Create is where the list of objects are created
    Create create = new Create();
    ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

    public void SetColor()
    {
        create = GetComponent<Create>();

        if (create.GraffitiLetters.Count > 0)
        {
            colorPicker = GetComponent<ColorPicker>();
            for (int i = 0; i < create.GraffitiLetters.Count; i++)
            {
               create.GraffitiLetters[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = colorPicker.GetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I bet it has something to do with me having to get hold of the component first but I dunno?

----------------------EDIT--------------------------

OK, new attempt for the same problem.

I have a class called ColorPicker. Inside of it I have a Color color; which gets an rgba value.

Now I want to grab that value from another class. How?

Inside my Paint class I tried this.

```
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
colorPicker = GameObject.Find("color").GetComponent<ColorPicker>();
Debug.Log(colorPicker.color);
```

I've also tried various other ways but I just don't get it. seems like a simple problem.

--------- Second edit------------------

I have tried all of these. I can't understand it. all the questions that seem similar has gotten one of these answers. nothing works for me.

```
//This Gets NullReferenceException
    //Debug.Log("test color" + colorPicker.GetComponent<ColorPicker>          ().GetColor());

    //This Gets NullReferenceException
    //colorPicker.GetComponent<Color>();
    //Debug.Log("test 2" + colorPicker.color);

    //This Gets NullReferenceException
   // colorPicker.transform.Find("color");
   // colorPicker.GetComponent<Color>();
   // Debug.Log("test 3 " + colorPicker.color);
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what line gives the Null Reference Exception, so proper help cannot be given. I will write down some things that may be the issue:

> Create create = new Create();

This is not the issue, but it's confusing. I don't think you want to instansiate this class, it makes no sense. What value is an empty instance. You're later setting it to this GameObject's component, which makes sense through `create = GetComponent<Create>();`.

So I'll assume that `create` is null. This means you haven't attached the `Create` component/script to the GameObject that has the `Paint` script on it.

---

If that is not the case, I'm guessing your issue lies in the next step, namely that the `create.GraffitiLetters[i]` may not have an `Image` component.

---

Sidenote: Since your `Paint` class is dependant on its GameObject having a `Create` script, you could set an attribute on the class, that validates it for you:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Create))]
public class Paint: MonoBehaviour
```

Comment: Right...I'll do my best to deconstruct your reply and figure it out. thank you.

Comment: I could help more if you just told me/us the full error :) Specifically, where the exception arises.

Comment: Your exception will have a line number attached, showomg ypu exactly what is wrong

Comment: Ok...I've rearranged the code..still not found the solution but maybe this could explain it better. I have a class called ColorPicker, inside it I have a Color color; I want to grab the value of color from another class. How do I do that. I've tried everything I've found on the web. I know it has to do with it not having the proper reference but can't figure out how. I get a NullExceptionreference error.

Comment: So, if `ColorPicker` is a `MonoBehaviour` it means that it is a Component script, meaning it exists on a GameObject, and the GameObject exists in the world. So first you need to find the GameObject, then you need to GetComponent<ColorPicker>() on it. If someObject.GetComponent<ColorPicker>() is null, it means that either someObject is null, or that the someObject doesn't have a ColorPicker script attached to it.

Comment: Getting a reference to a GameObject can be done by (1) explicit reference (you have a field that says `public GameObject someObject;` and it is assigned to a specific GameObject in the Unity Editor/Inspector. (2) Finding it in the scene by name: `GameObject.Find("some object");` or if it's a child to this GameObject: `transform.Find("some child object");` or (3) through things like collision `OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {  col.GameObject }`.